# Can not find module "vscode" in folder node_modules. How the module call is resolved

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

Generated the below code using "yo code" for extension with "JavaScript". I need to understand where is the actual "vscode" module as I could not found it anywhere in the workspace including folder "node_modules".

Please note that the below code is working fine(with F5 , debug mode run).

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', function () {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from HelloWorld!');
        vscode.window.showQuickPick(['a', 'b', 'c']).then((value) => {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

I searched in workspace including "node_modules" but could not found vscode as a module

```
[npm list]
╰─❯❯❯ npm list
helloworld@0.0.1 D:\aditya_panda\Workspace\VSCode-WorkSpace\JS_EDI_editor_plugin_vscode\javascript\helloworld
├── @types/mocha@10.0.1
├── @types/node@16.18.50
├── @types/vscode@1.82.0
├── @vscode/test-electron@2.3.4
├── eslint@8.49.0
├── glob@10.3.4
├── mocha@10.2.0
└── typescript@5.2.2
```

I found below answer, but can someone explain how it work?

> *VS Code intercepts calls to require made by extensions. If an extension calls require('vscode'), VS Code returns the api object: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8a7961905611212bf6da6ba9ba6e5bf1f48d2943/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostRequireInterceptor.ts#L85
>
> This means there is no corresponding vscode file on disk or under node_modules (only the typings are installed under node_modules)*

Comment: It seems you included some code, but it's improperly formatted, so it's hard to read. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on how to fix that, so you get your answer faster ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `require` function, provided by the VS Code extension system, special cases the request to require `'vscode'` and returns the object providing access to its API instead of loading a module in the normal way.